# How to assert for an exception while catching it at the same time?

Tags: java, exception, junit, junit4

I am building a program for poker hands and comparing cards for my Object-Oriented programming class. When a create a new PokerHand object, I pass into it 5 card ojects. Then I need to check for any duplicate cards and if there are any, throw a new DuplicateCardException.

Here is the JUnit test for that exception:

```
@Test(expected = DuplicateCardException.class)
public void tryToAddTheSameCardTwice() {
    new PokerHand(C2, C3, C4, C5, C5);
}
```

You obviously can't have 2 5's of clubs so when comparing the cards, I throw the exception. But then I get the red bar and it fails. After much research, it sounds like it failed because I caught the exception so the JUnit test wasn't able to detect it. But if I don't catch it, then the compiler complains that the exception is not handled.

This is the method that throws the exception (card4 and card5 are both "C5" objects):

```
public void checkForDuplicates() {
    try {
        if(card4==card5)
            throw new DuplicateCardException();

    } catch (DuplicateCardException e) {e.printStackTrace();}       
}
```

So my question is how do I let the JUnit test know the exception was thrown without changing the actual testing code? (since that is what I'm being graded with) I've tried adding "throws DuplicateCardException" in the method headers instead of having a try/catch block including in the test area and then it passes, but I can't change the testing code.

Comment: Rethrow it after you've printed it?

If you've caught it, and not rethrown it, it is NOT an expected result of the method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test expected an Exception, Exception was thrown (it shows in the output) but test failed anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118207/test-expected-an-exception-exception-was-thrown-it-shows-in-the-output-but-te)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to edit the code but aren't allowed to edit the test case to add a `throws` declaration, you may need to make the exception unchecked. This is achieved by extending from `RuntimeException` (or a subclass of it), instead of `Exception`.

Comment: And I got the green bar. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to declare your exception in the throws clause of your test method.

```
@Test(expected = DuplicateCardException.class)
public void tryToAddTheSameCardTwice() throws DuplicateCardException {
    new PokerHand(C2, C3, C4, C5, C5);
}
```

So that the compiler will not complain. During execution of your test, the exception will be thrown and catch by Junit which will report the test as OK (green) because you tell him so (annotation @Test(expected = DuplicateCardException.class)).