# Test expected an Exception, Exception was thrown (it shows in the output) but test failed anyway

Tags: java, junit, exception

Hi so there's a test for a constructor for a vehicle. The test initializes a vehicle with a driver without a driving license and it should throw an Exception. 
code constructor:

```
public Voertuig(String Merk, Datum datumEersteIngebruikname, int Aankoopprijs, int Zitplaatsen, Mens bestuurder, Mens ... ingezetenen) {
    this.nummerplaat = div.getNummerplaat();
    this.Zitplaatsen = Zitplaatsen;
    try {

        this.Merk = Merk;
        this.datumEersteIngebruikname = datumEersteIngebruikname;
        this.Aankoopprijs = Aankoopprijs;
        if (!Arrays.asList(bestuurder.getRijbewijs()).contains(Rijbewijs.B) || !Arrays.asList(bestuurder.getRijbewijs()).contains(Rijbewijs.BE)) {
            throw new MensException("Geen correct rijbewijs");
        } else {
            this.bestuurder = bestuurder;
            Ingezetenen.add(bestuurder);
        }
        Mens[] a = ingezetenen;
        if (a.length > Zitplaatsen - 1) {
            throw new MensException("te veel ingezetenen");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                ingezetenenExclBestuurder.add(a[i]);
                Ingezetenen.add(a[i]);
            }
        }

    } catch (MensException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

code test:

```
 @Test(expected = be.vdab.util.mens.MensException.class)
    public void test_constructor_zonder_Rijbewijs() {
     //VOERTUIG B,BE//bestuurder:---
        Voertuig voertuig = new TestVoertuig("auto", datum, 18300, AANTAL_INZITTENDEN, INGEZETENE_A);
}
```

and when i run this focused test method this is the outcome.

------------- Standard Output ---------------

Geen correct rijbewijs

---

```
Testcase: Testcase: test_constructor_zonder_Rijbewijs(be.vdab.voertuigen.VoertuigTest): FAILED
Expected exception: be.vdab.util.mens.MensException
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Expected exception: be.vdab.util.mens.MensException
```

So according to the Output the Exception is caught and displayed but yet the test failed. Anybody knows why? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I fixed it by not including a try-catch block but just throwing the exception resulting in having to add 'throws MensException' in every test-method where it was creating an object. I fixed this by adjusting my custom MensException, instead of extending Exception i had it extend RuntimeException so i didn't have to add 'throws MensException' in every test-method.

Comment: You caught the exception and handled it. If you expect an exception, throw it. Also make sure to note the method should be expected to throw said exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method, you're capturing the exception and logging the message (which is a bad practice, you should log the stacktrace) and in your test you state that the execution of the test **must** throw a `be.vdab.util.mens.MensException` without being catched.

Just re throw it or don't catch it at all in the method/constructor being tested.

Option 1:

```
public Voertuig(/*  ...your arguments here... */) {
    this.nummerplaat = div.getNummerplaat();
    this.Zitplaatsen = Zitplaatsen;
    try {
        //...
        //code in the try...
        //...
    } catch (MensException e) {
        //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        //use a logger, not System.out
        //in case you still want to use System.out
        //then at least use the code shown below
        //e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        //line above commented since there's no need to log
        //and rethrow the exception
        //the exception will be handled by the highest level execution
        //and there it should be logged or use another strategy
        throw e;
    } 
}
```

Option 2:

```
public Voertuig(/*  ...your arguments here... */) {
    this.nummerplaat = div.getNummerplaat();
    this.Zitplaatsen = Zitplaatsen;
//remove the try
//    try {
    //...
    //code in the try...
    //...
//remove the catch
//    } catch (MensException e) {
//        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
//    } 
}
```

IMO I would use option 2 rather than option 1.

Comment: Ah yeah, thanks so i was actually handling the Exception allready in the constructor and then its gone. Ok thanks guys for all the info!

Comment: Either log or throw, not both. Logging is "handling" the exception. If you log and throw it will get "handled" twice.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually catching the exception in the catch block. That's why your test failed not getting the expected exception.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
    } catch (MensException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

You catch the exception  so it is not thrown to the test class.

Change to to:

```
} catch (MensException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    throw e
}
```

Comment: That's bad practice. Either log or throw, not both. Logging is "handling" the exception. If you log and throw it will get "handled" twice.