# How to catch this custom Java exception?

Tags: java, junit, exception, tdd

I've got the following unit test:

```
public class Update {

    @Rule
    public final ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

    private Update update;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.update = new Update();
    }

    @Test
    public void validateThrowsExceptionIfMissingId() throws BadParameterException {
        this.update.setId(null);

        exception.expect(NotFoundException.class);
        exception.expectMessage("Error");
        this.categoryUpdateRequest.validate();
    }
}
```

Which is expecting a custom NotFoundException I am throwing. The problem is that, even I can see the exception is being thrown in the console, my test is not getting it:

```
com.project.api.exception.NotFoundException: Error.
```

Any hint please?

Comment: Is your test passing or failing? Show us what `CategoryUpdateRequest` is.

Comment: It's failing, I'll update with CategoryUpdateRequest

Comment: Does `this.categoryUpdateRequest.validate();` internally catch the exception and call `exception.printStacktrace()`? In this case please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118207/test-expected-an-exception-exception-was-thrown-it-shows-in-the-output-but-te

Comment: @StefanBirkner updated question

Comment: Does `globalExceptionHandler.handleBadParameter` rethrow the exception or only handle it?

Comment: @StefanBirkner I added what it does in the updated question now, thanks for your kind help in advance

Comment: `this.categoryUpdateRequest.validate();` does not throw an exception. Hence your test is failing. You can only test the effect of `validate()` to the outside world. I think you are using the globalExceptionHandler wrong, because you don't use its return value and the annotation `@ResponseBody` must be interpreted by a framework.

Comment: @StefanBirkner WELL DONE! Damn! I don't know how could I missed it! Write that in an answer and I'll mark it as solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Junit test you write expects an exception to be thrown. Your code does not throw an exception. It just creates an instance of the Exception and calls a (sort of) exception handling function.

You can see the "exception" because you created an exception instance and sent it to the logger. But actually for you system it's never a real exception, as you never `throw` it.

JUnit is absolutely right in complaining that an exception has not been thrown.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [TestNG](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/ExpectedExceptions.html) `@Test` annotation parameter `expectedExceptions`.

Here is an example:

```
public class CategoryUpdateRequestTest 
{

    private CategoryUpdateRequest categoryUpdateRequest;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        this.categoryUpdateRequest = new CategoryUpdateRequest();
    }

    @Test(
        expectedExceptions = { NotFoundException.class },
        expectedExceptionsMessageRegExp = "Category object is missing Category id."
    )
    public void validateThrowsExceptionIfMissingCategoryId() throws Exception {
        this.categoryUpdateRequest.setId(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, but I'd like to use @Rule. Do you know how to add TestNG to Gradle?

Comment: Hi @stackpepe, you can add testng to your project by adding
`testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'` to the `dependancy` section of your `build.gradle` file.